# Chat application in Android using Parse Server

Tags: android, chat, real-time, parse-server, livequery

I have to develop an Android chat application and i have **Parse Server** as a backend.

I read documentations about **Live Query** it can do the job for **real-time** tasks, but this solution is only available for iOS.

Is there a way to use Live Queries for Android or should i use another solution with **Parse Server** such as **Firebase** ?

Comment: I really loved Parse, but i would rather develop new apps in Firebase...

Comment: The answer to this question is **use PubNub**.  the normal course of action is to use PubNub+Parse, or PubNub+Firebase .. or PubNub+whatever.

Comment: @MazelTov .. back4app now works absolutely, totally identically to the old parse.com.  Everyone just uses back4app.com, it "is" Parse with a new name.

Comment: @JoeBlow ...back4app looks nice, but you should also consider Google services and SDK vs. back4app as hosting and parse-server as open source...

Comment: hey @MazelTov - I mean - it's only Parse. You know?  I can't really imagine bothering with anything other than back4app.  (it's hosted on AWS absolutely identically to if you do it yourself.)  "Everyone" simply uses back4app, for that reason I think.  Anyway - cheers!

Comment: @MazelTov Parse Server is already set up and i'm using it as Backend.

Comment: I think @JoeBlow solution is what i'm looking for : **Parse Server** + **PubNub**.

Comment: hi @Fadwa_lmh.  sure, it's an absolute basic of mobile engineering today that you use PubNub for "anything like chat".  it is "the" planet's presence delivery network.  You might as well say "to search on your computer, use Google!"  How else could you do it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JoeBlow

Answer (score 4):

You can combine Parse Server and [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com). When A wants to send a message to B, A save that message to Parse then you write cloud code in [afterSave Triggers](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/cloudcode/guide/#aftersave-triggers) to publish the message to B via PubNub.

Comment: Exactly correct. Chat apps (or anything like that) are done with PubNub.  In terms of the questioner's question, Firebase/Parse/Etc have nothing to do with chat -like technology.  You use PubNub *in conjunction with* Parse, Firebase - or whatever baas.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Haven , i did some research and as i understand i'll store data in my Parse and PubNub is for the real-time job?

Comment: Can i use **PubNub GeoHash** for chating with people nearby ? or i need to combine it with Google maps or Google places?

Comment: hi @Fadwa_lmh.  You can't just keep asking questions here.  BE SURE TO "TICK" Haven's answer.  If you have a NEW question, go ahead and ask a new question.  OK?